# PHP imagettftext: bounding boxes of letters superimpose above each other

Tags: php, image, letters, imagettftext

I'm writing text-images on the fly with PHPs `imagettftext`, which works fine so far, but I have a very strange problem.

We are using a very italicized font and apparently the bounding boxes of later letters are sometimes superimposing their background over previous letters, thus cutting into them.

Now, I can't seem to find a way to tell imagettftext to use a transparent background for the font (for the image itself it's not a problem).

So, anyone has an suggestion how to get rid of those cuts? Or will we have to use a less italicized font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ha, found the solution right after posting the question.

I had user imagealphablending($image, false) to get a transparent background.
When turning it back on right before applying the text, it works just fine.